# Can we obtain an access token for an Azure resource using a standalone user-assigned managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

What are the uses of a standalone user-assigned managed identity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can obtain an access token for an Azure resource using a user assigned MI. It works like a regular app registration.